# Axios. How to get error response even when api return 404 error, in try catch finally

Tags: javascript, error-handling, axios

for e.g.

```
(async() => {
  let apiRes = null;
  try {
    apiRes = await axios.get('https://silex.edgeprop.my/api/v1/a');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } finally {
    console.log(apiRes);
  }
})();
```

in `finally`, `apiRes` will return null.

Even when the api get a 404 response, there is still useful information in the response that I would like to use.

How can I use the error response in `finally` when axios throws error.

https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/fdvnsg6u/1/

Comment: Pesumably the useful info you're talking about is in `err`? I can't see why you want it in the `finally` rather than the `catch`, but if you do, simply save it in the `catch` to a variable you can access in the `finally`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the error in `catch` doesn't contain the api response. if I can get around this then your method would work !

Comment: Yes, it does. (I just browsed the documentation.)

Answer (score 121, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors), the full response is available as a `response` property on the error.

So I'd use that information in the `catch` block:

```
(async() => {
  let apiRes = null;
  try {
    apiRes = await axios.get('https://silex.edgeprop.my/api/v1/a');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error response:");
    console.error(err.response.data);    // ***
    console.error(err.response.status);  // ***
    console.error(err.response.headers); // ***
  } finally {
    console.log(apiRes);
  }
})();
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fdvnsg6u/2/)

But if you want it in `finally` instead, just save it to a variable you can use there:

```
(async() => {
  let apiRes = null;
  try {
    apiRes = await axios.get('https://silex.edgeprop.my/api/v1/a');
  } catch (err) {
    apiRes = err.response;
  } finally {
    console.log(apiRes); // Could be success or error
  }
})();
```

Comment: You can also see the `err` type definition [here](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/index.d.ts#L85) to find other useful data :)

Answer (score 85):

According to the AXIOS documentation (here: https://github.com/axios/axios) you can pass `validateStatus: false` in the config object to any axios request.

e.g.

```
axios.get(url, { validateStatus: false })
axios.post(url, postBody, { validateStatus: false })
```

You can also pass a function like this: `validateStatus: (status) => status === 200`
According to the docs the default behaviour is function that returns true if (200 <= status < 300).

Comment: Thanks! used this as an option
`const options = { method: 'GET', headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json'}, url: 'url, validateStatus: false };`

Comment: Thank you, I think that try catch is ugly and over blows the code base. This is solving it...

Comment: Can't believe how much time I spent trying to figure out why I was getting 404. This simple fix was all I needed.

Comment: Great! My Axios instance ignored errors with a 404 status by default. It just threw an error to the console, ignored the rest of the code, and even disregarded the code after the `await` in an async function. That helped, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can treate the status code:

exemple using Ts:

```
let conf: AxiosRequestConfig = {};

    conf.validateStatus = (status: number) => {
        
        return (status >= 200 && status < 300) || status == 404
    }

    let response = await req.get(url, conf);
```

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the accepted solution `{ validateStatus: false }`:

It's also important to note that you will still see the same error message on the line with axios.get(....)

However the code proceeds in the ".then(...)" part. This is a strange behaviour which cost me a lot of testing time, because I thought that the setting had no affect.