# On catching error, model closes but I want to display error

Tags: reactjs

Axios request which is called from `onSubmit` the form.

I have tried many times but, on `catch` the error model closes automatically. I don't want it to close, I want to display the error in models

```
axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/login", finaldata)

.then( (res) => {
      } )
          .catch( function (err) {
        console.log("error", err.response.data)
      });
```

For close button `this.props.close` which passes from previous component to this

```
close=()=>{this.props.close()}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/login",finaldata)
.then(response => { 
    console.log(response)
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error.response)
});
```

You can also refer to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49967779/axios-handling-errors) and [this](https://gist.github.com/fgilio/230ccd514e9381fafa51608fcf137253), and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48298890/axios-how-to-get-error-response-even-when-api-return-404-error-in-try-catch-fi)

Comment: no it is also not working model closes immediately when it catches the  error

Comment: what should i do?

Comment: i also tried the other things but model still closes

Comment: ahh my logical mistake unfortunately i use the check for redirecting but thanks to you i found the bug

Comment: @muneeb bukhari glad I could help you :) Thank u for accepting my answer !