# How can I get response body for 404 in Axios?

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm calling an API that returns 404 and a message in the body.

I want to get that message in Axios.

I saw [Axios. How to get error response even when api return 404 error, in try catch finally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48298890/axios-how-to-get-error-response-even-when-api-return-404-error-in-try-catch-fi) but it does not work.

I also tried `error.response.response` but it's undefined.

How can I get the textual response from 404?

Comment: your question is very much unclear, do share code snippet (IN TEXT) of API and also the frontend where you are consuming the api

Comment: @YashSoni, it's not hard. API returns 404 with `text/plain` response type and I can't get that text from the response body.

Answer (score 0):

try the example set in https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors

in particular: error.message or error.response

Comment: This did not work. I tried `error.response.data` but that's empty.

Comment: can you log only error and show us the response by editing your question