# How to print the result from an axios post request

Tags: reactjs, redux, promise, axios

I want to save in localStorage my token from server(server it's made in java) but the code below doesn't work so I want to print `res` too see what data do I get from server.

I tried to print to console with `res.data.text()` and `res.data.json()` but doesn't work.

```
    return dispatch =>{
        return api.user.login(userData).then(res =>{
             const token = res.data;
             console.log(token);
             //localStorage.setItem('jwtToken',token);

        })
}
```

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
    user:{
        login:(credentials) => axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/auth/signin',credentials).then(res=>res.data.user)
    }
}
```

The post request works on the server, but it gets stuck when I want to print.By stuck I mean when I press the login button nothing happens.

How can I print into the console `res`?

Comment: What do you mean it gets stuck? What is error you are getting?

Also, what is your api.user.login? Could you post the whole code.

Comment: can you create a sandbox

Comment: what is res actually printing?

Comment: console.log(res) will print something like user object I guess because you already returned user from the request

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Axios - How to read JSON response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48062821/axios-how-to-read-json-response)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to convert json object to string to see on console

```
return dispatch =>{
        return api.user.login(userData).then(res =>{
             const token = res.data;
             console.log(JSON.Stringify(res));
             //localStorage.setItem('jwtToken',token);

        })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/auth/signin',credentials)
    .then(
        res=>console.log(res.data.user)
    )
```

Try this. I have written a `console.log()` inside the `.then` function. If it still doesn't work, try logging `res` instead of `res.data.user` and check the result

Answer (score 0):

For a successful request:

```
  return dispatch => api.user.login(userData)
      .then(res => console.log(res.data))
```

For a unsuccessful request:

Logging the error request you'll print the error object.

```
    return dispatch => api.user.login(userData)
      .then(res => console.log(res.data))
      .catch(error => console.log(error.request))
```

To store the token:

```
localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', JSON.stringfy(token))
```