# How to get data from API response

Tags: javascript, json, api, axios

this function returns API response,
I would like to get a specific field value, let's say "price" from this response, how do I do that?

```js
export const getprice = async () => {
    return await axios.get(
        "https://api.pancakeswap.info/api/v2/tokens/0x0e09fabb73bd3ade0a17ecc321fd13a19e81ce82"
    );
};
```

function returns this:

```json
{"updated_at":1620658369033,"data":{"name":"PancakeSwap Token","symbol":"Cake","price":"40.19439880437819571616287343907344","price_BNB":"0.05840738921546340105964944169352627"}
```

By the way, the API token is public.

Comment: Is that a **private** api token? People might abuse it...

Comment: @0stone0 no private api it's public

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Axios - How to read JSON response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48062821/axios-how-to-read-json-response)

Answer (score 1):

```
export const getPrice = async () => {
    let price = await requestData().then(response=>response.data['price'])
    return price
};
async function requestData(){
    try{
        let response = await axios.get("https://api.pancakeswap.info/api/v2/tokens/0x0e09fabb73bd3ade0a17ecc321fd13a19e81ce82")
        return response;
    }catch(error){
        //do something with error
    }
}
```

P.S. Don't show anyone private api tokens

Comment: Mixing `await` and `then` is typically not a good idea, but i guess OP already used the `return await` anti-pattern as well, so whatever.