# Vue-Select: How can I convert this fetch() code to use axios?

Tags: vuejs2, axios, vue-select

I am trying to use the [vue-select](https://vue-select.org/guide/ajax.html#loading-options-with-ajax) package in my application. I have some code that I copied from the docs and it works fine. However, I would like to convert it to use axios instead of `fetch()` for readability and also so I can use my own axios configuration settings.

How can I convert the following code to use axios instead of fetch?

```
    search: debounce((loading, search, vm) => {
      fetch(
        `https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=${escape(search)}`
      ).then((res) => {
        res.json().then((json) => (vm.options = json.items))
        loading(false)
      })
    }, 350)
```

I tried the below code but I got an error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: res is not a function`:

```
    search: debounce(async (loading, search, vm) => {
      await axios
        .get(`https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=${escape(search)}`)
        .then((res) => {
          res((json) => (vm.options = json.items))
          loading(false)
        })
    }, 350)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `res()` as a function when it's an object. You likely meant `res.json()` coming from fetch. This shouldn't be necessary with axios, you can [access the json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65976510/8723748) with `res.data`.

Also you're mixing promise/async which suprisingly doesn't throw an error (.then() shouldnt be defined after awaiting), but makes the code tough to read. Use one or the other.

Async

```
{
    search: debounce(async (loading, search, vm) => {
        let res = await axios.get(`https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=${escape(search)}`)
        const items = res.data
        vm.options = items
        loading(false)
    }, 350)
}
```

Promise

```
{ 
    search: debounce((loading, search, vm) => {
        axios
            .get(`https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=${escape(search)}`)
            .then((res) => {
                const items = res.data
                vm.options = items
                loading(false)
            })
    }, 350)
}
```

IMO I find fetch() easier to read, plus it has native support.